# Put status on item

Tags: php, html

I would like to put status on item. When the quantity is `0` it should come out `Sold Out` else `Available`. But I'm getting a parse error on line 16. Why is that?

```
<?php 

// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$dynamicList = "";
$status = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
       $id = $row["id"];
       $product_name = $row["product_name"];
       $price = $row["price"];
       $quantity = $row["quantity"];
       $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
       $status = if($quantity == 0) echo "Sold Out";
                 else echo "Available";
       $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="6">
         <tr>
          <td width="17%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 0px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></a></td>
          <td width="83%" valign="top">       
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br />
            $' . $price . '<br />
            Quantity =' .$quantity . ' 
            <br /> Status = ' . $status . ' <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` ?! You should consider moving on with the world...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your code : you can't assign value to the `if` statement  while `echo`ing something in it.Try the following :

```
  $status = $quantity == 0 ? "Sold Out" : "Available";
  echo $status;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely wrong syntax-wise:

$status = if($quantity == 0) echo "Sold Out";
             else echo "Available";

Try this instead:

if ($quantity == 0)
     $status = "Sold Out";
   else
     $status = "Available";
   echo $status;